# How to interact with terminal in ipython notebook?

Tags: python, linux, ipython

When I unzipped a file in ipython notebook using caffe codes :
!home/feyman/caffe/data/mnist/get_mnist.sh
!home/feyman/caffe/examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh

I got a message like that:

Unzipping...
gzip: train-images-idx3-ubyte already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?

It asked me to type y or n to make the unzipping move on..
But where and how should I type that ? 
I've tried to type y in ipython notebook and terminal, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: How exactly are you unzipped that file? Are you using the Python module, or an external process? and how?

Comment: caffe codes: !home/feyman/caffe/data/mnist/get_mnist.sh
!home/feyman/caffe/examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh

Comment: I have no idea what that is, and the scripts are obviously obscure. But the fact that you're using the exclamation marks does tell you the cause of the problem: you just handed off the control from IPython to the shell, thus you can't use IPython anymore to interact with anything in the script. You'll need to code it into your script. One option is to use something like a `--force` flag to always override.